# Unable to get the proper format and structure of a simple web page using Angular, which was achieved earlier using simple HTML, CSS code

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Firstly, I have achieved the web page design using simple HTML and CSS files but when I executed the same using Angular using left, right and middle components, it is failing to give me the same desired output. Below is the detailed code using Angular:

**left.component.html**

```
    <div class="left">
  <img class="img" src="assets/Z1.jpg" alt="Z1" />
  <div class="frame20">
    <div class="frame18">
      <p class="zip">ZIP</p>
      <p class="msg">Messenger</p>
    </div>
    <div class="frame19">
      <img
        class="image"
        style="background: url(assets/V1.jpg), lightgray 50% / cover no-repeat"
        src="assets/V1.jpg"
        alt="V1"
      />
      <img
        class="image"
        style="background: url(assets/S1.jpg), lightgray 50% / cover no-repeat"
        src="assets/S1.jpg"
        alt="S1"
      />
      <img
        class="image"
        style="background: url(assets/G1.jpg), lightgray 50% / cover no-repeat"
        src="assets/G1.jpg"
        alt="G1"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**left.component.css** :

```
.left {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.img {
  width: 99px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url("/assets/Z1.jpg"), lightgray 50% / cover no-repeat;
}

.frame20 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
}

.frame18 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.frame19 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  gap: -30px;
}

.zip {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Inter;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: normal;
}
.msg {
  color: var(--label-text, #c7c7c7);
  font-family: Inter;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;
}
.image {
  width: 69px;
  height: 69px;
}
```

**left.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-left',
  templateUrl: './left.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./left.component.css'],
})
export class LeftComponent {}
```

**middle.component.html** :

```
<div class="middle">
  <div class="frame15">
    <div class="frame17">
      <p class="msg17">Message</p>
      <p class="submsg17">Enter message below</p>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="rect"></div>-->

    <div class="rect"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**middle.component.css** :

```
.middle {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 14px;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  align-self: stretch;
}
.frame15 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  align-self: stretch;
}
.frame17 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: stretch;
}
.msg17 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Inter;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: normal;
}
.submsg17 {
  color: var(--label-text, #c7c7c7);
  font-family: Inter;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;
}
.rect {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  align-self: stretch;
  border: 1px solid #ababab;
}
```

**middle.component.ts** :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-middle',
  templateUrl: './middle.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./middle.component.css'],
})
export class MiddleComponent {}
```

**right.component.html** :

```
<div class="right">
  <button class="btn1"><p class="send">SEND</p></button>
  <button class="btn2"><p class="cancel">CANCEL</p></button>
</div>
```

**right.component.css** :

```
.right {
  display: flex;
  width: 184px;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-self: stretch;
}
.btn1 {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  align-self: stretch;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: var(--button-affirm, #32c1ff);
}
.btn2 {
  display: flex;
  height: 53px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  align-self: stretch;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #f00;
}
.send {
  color: var(--button-text, #fff);
  font-family: Inter;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
}
.cancel {
  color: var(--button-text, #fff);
  font-family: Inter;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

**right.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-right',
  templateUrl: './right.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./right.component.css'],
})
export class RightComponent {}
```

**app.component.html** (css and html both inside this file):

```
 <style>
  .layout {
    display: flex;
    width: 1188px;
    height: 757px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .left {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: stretch;
  }
  .middle {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 14px;
    flex: 1 0 0;
    align-self: stretch;
  }
  .right {
    display: flex;
    width: 184px;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    align-self: stretch;
  }
</style>
    
    <div class="layout">
  <div class="left"><app-left></app-left></div>
  <div class="middle"><app-middle></app-middle></div>
  <div class="right"><app-right></app-right></div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts** :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**app.module.ts** :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LeftComponent } from 'src/components/left/left.component';
import { MiddleComponent } from 'src/components/middle/middle.component';
import { RightComponent } from 'src/components/right/right.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, LeftComponent, MiddleComponent, RightComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

What is to be achieved from the Figma design is this (ignore the black bar part on the top). This has been achieved through simple HTML and CSS code(this is to be the output):

[image]

What I am getting using Angular, is this :

[image]

Please help me in fixing the above issue. Where am I going wrong, if anyone could pinpoint it.

Comment: The two screenshots are the same picture. Also, this question is about Angular, and not AngularJS. Please edit the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I would expect exactly the second screenshot after checking for html & css. You have to keep in mind, that you have additional elements in your html. left, middle and right. As you did not style them it looks like this. Instead of defining a root element in each component as a div with class left, right, middle ... take the element of the component itself.

Comment: I have removed the root elements from left, right, middle and also removed the root element from app.component.html, but still its failing to show the output as per the first screenshot.